# What is proper way to get rid of quarantined files after ClamXav scan?

Tags: imac, virus, high-sierra

I used ClamXav to scan my iMac for viruses. Now that I have them quarantined (19 files) do I just put them in the trash? Or is there a different method to making sure these are gone and won't be a problem anymore?

I have attached a pic. Are these just all email/spam/phish?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the infected files have been moved to a defined quarantine folder, i.e., e.g., ClamXav > Preferences > Quarantine Preferences > Set quarantine folder, then in Finder, select the files in the quarantine folder and right-click > Move to Trash, then empty the Trash.

Note: The `*.emlx` files are the entire email files, as ClamXav cannot just remove the spam/virus/malware/etc. portion of the email.  The `*.partial.emlx` file are partially downloaded email files that contain spam/virus/malware/etc.